# Magnus expansion and two point Gauss quadrature rule

Tags: integration, numerical-methods, matrix-exponential, quadrature

In many papers about *Magnus integrators*, like [this one at slide
7](https://na.math.kit.edu/marlis/download/talks/05helsinki_hochbruck.pdf), one truncates the Magnus expansion and apply a quadrature rule to the integrals.

My question is about the expression one gets if uses just the first two terms  and apply **two-points Gauss quadrature rule** with nodes $c_{1,2}=\frac{1}{2} \mp \frac{\sqrt{3}}{6}$.

The term to approximate is $$\int_0^h A(t_n + \tau) d \tau - \frac{1}{2}\int_0^h [\int_0^{\tau}A(t_n+ \sigma) d\sigma,A(t_n+\tau)] d \tau$$

where $$[\cdot,\cdot]$$ is the classical commutator.

---

For the first integral it's easy to see that applying Gauss quadrature rule with those $c_1,c_2$ its approximation is $$ \frac{h}{2}(A(t_n + c_1 h) + A(t_n + c_2h))$$

**My question is about the other one**: I'm having serious problem in finding the term in the literature

What I have to approximate is $$\int_0^h [\int_0^{\tau}A(t_n+ \sigma) d\sigma,A(t_n+\tau)] d \tau$$

The first thing that I had in mind is to see the inner part of the integral as a function of $\tau$,i.e. $$f(\tau)=[\int_0^{\tau}A_n(\sigma) d \sigma,A_n(\tau)]$$

and hence I see my integral as $I = \int_0^h f(\tau) d \tau$

Now, applying Gauss 2-point quadrature I get

$$ I \approx \frac{h}{2}(f(c_1 h)+f(c_2 h))$$

The problem is that now I don't know how to see that it is equal to $\frac{\sqrt{3}}{12}h^2[A_n(c_2h),A_n(c_1h)]$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A journal reference with explanation and analysis is

*Iserles, A.; Nørsett, S. P.*, [**On the solution of lienar differential equations in Lie groups**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1098/rsta.1999.0362), Philos. Trans. R. Soc. Lond., Ser. A, Math. Phys. Eng. Sci. 357, No. 1754, 983-1019 (1999). [ZBL0958.65080](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0958.65080).

See the discussion after Corollary 3.3 in particular. The idea is to approximate $A$ by an interpolating polynomial, in this case

$$A(x)\approx A(c_1h)\frac{x-c_2h}{c_1h-c_2h} + A(c_2h)\frac{x-c_1h}{c_2h-c_1h}$$

I'll set $t_n=0$ and $h=1.$ Then
\begin{align*}
&\int_0^h \int_0^\kappa [A(\xi),A(\kappa)] \;d\xi \;d\kappa\\
&\approx[A(c_1),A(c_2)]\int_0^1 \int_0^\kappa \frac{\xi-c_2}{c_1-c_2}\frac{\kappa-c_1}{c_2-c_1}-\frac{\kappa-c_2}{c_1-c_2}\frac{\xi-c_1}{c_2-c_1} \;d\xi \;d\kappa\\
&=[A(c_1),A(c_2)]\int_0^1 \int_0^\kappa \frac{\kappa-\xi}{c_2-c_1} \;d\xi \;d\kappa\\
&=[A(c_1),A(c_2)]\int_0^1 \frac{\tfrac12\kappa^2}{c_2-c_1} \;d\kappa\\
&=[A(c_1),A(c_2)]\frac{\sqrt{3}}{6}
\end{align*}

Going back to the original question, the term you're asking about is

$$
- \frac{1}{2}\int_0^h [\int_0^{\tau}A(t_n+ \sigma) d\sigma,A(t_n+\tau)] \;d \tau$$
Changing variable names (to match the Iserles and Nørsett reference), setting $t_n=0,$ and pulling out the integral, this term is
\begin{align*}
&- \frac{1}{2}\int_0^h \int_0^{\kappa}[A(\xi),A(\kappa)] \;d\xi \;d \kappa\\
&=-\frac12 [A(c_1),A(c_2)]\frac{\sqrt{3}}{6}\qquad\text{ by the previous calculation}\\
&=\frac12 [A(c_2),A(c_1)]\frac{\sqrt{3}}{6}\qquad\text{because $[a,b]=-[b,a]$}\\
&=[A(c_2),A(c_1)]\frac{\sqrt{3}}{12}
\end{align*}

Comment: Since this is a 400rep question, it would be nice to include even the details you mention in the last sentence.

Comment: As wrote by @b00nheT, could you be a little more explicit in the last sentence?

Comment: @VoB: sure, I have added more detail

Comment: Thanks, perfect